Upload jena-fuseki dataset from command line
I want to upload jena-fuseki's dataset in a linux shell script before running unit test set.
I've tried the following commands:

~/jena_for_unit_testing/apache-jena-fuseki-3.13.1> ./fuseki-server  --update --file ds_2024-04-25_13-58-06.nq.gz --port 3031 /test

~/jena_for_unit_testing/apache-jena-fuseki-3.13.1> ./fuseki-server --config run/config.ttl --update --file ds_2024-04-25_13-58-06.nq.gz --port 3031

~/jena_for_unit_testing/apache-jena-fuseki-3.13.1> ./fuseki-server --config run/config.ttl --update --port 3031


config.ttl:
# Licensed under the terms of http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

## Fuseki Server configuration file.

@prefix :        <#> .
@prefix fuseki:  <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .

<#service1> rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
    fuseki:name "ds" ;
    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:query ;];
    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:query ; fuseki:name "sparql" ];
    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:query ; fuseki:name "query" ];

    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:update ; ];
    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:update ; fuseki:name "update" ];

    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:gsp-r ; fuseki:name "get" ];
    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:gsp-rw ; ] ;
    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:gsp-rw ; fuseki:name "data" ];
    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:upload ; fuseki:name "upload" ] ;
    fuseki:dataset <#test>
    .
<#test> rdf:type ja:RDFDataset .

In 1) I cannot update my dataset (Error 404: No endpoint: /test/update)
In 2) I get the error: Dataset specified on the command line but a configuration file also given.
In 3) I can update my dataset, but I don't know how to upload ds_2024-04-25_13-58-06.nq.gz from command line before starting unit tests.
Edit:
Based on answers below I've also tried upload data using command:   curl -i -XPOST "http://localhost:3031/ds" --data-binary ds_2024-04-25_13-58-06.nq --header "Content-type: application/n-quads"
where my nq-file looks like this:
~/jena_for_unit_testing/apache-jena-fuseki-3.13.1> head  ds_2024-04-25_13-58-06.nq

<http://www.<myOrg>.fi/tilasto/tilastot_slv> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.<myOrg>.fi/rdf/ontologies/pxproNG> .
<http://www.<myOrg>.fi/tilasto/tilastot_teul> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.<myOrg>.fi/rdf/ontologies/pxproNG> .
<http://www.<myOrg>.fi/tilasto/tilastot_ton> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.<myOrg>.fi/rdf/ontologies/pxproNG> .
<http://www.<myOrg>.fi/tilasto/tilastot_ttvi> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.<myOrg>.fi/rdf/ontologies/pxproNG> .
<http://www.<myOrg>.fi/tilasto/tilastot_khki> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.<myOrg>.fi/rdf/ontologies/pxproNG> .
<http://www.<myOrg>.fi/tilasto/tilastot_sijk> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.<myOrg>.fi/rdf/ontologies/pxproNG> .
<http://www.<myOrg>.fi/tilasto/tilastot_ktps> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.<myOrg>.fi/rdf/ontologies/pxproNG> .
<http://www.<myOrg>.fi/tilasto/tilastot_klv> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.<myOrg>.fi/rdf/ontologies/pxproNG> .
<http://www.<myOrg>.fi/tilasto/tilastot_adopt> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.<myOrg>.fi/rdf/ontologies/pxproNG> .
<http://www.<myOrg>.fi/tilasto/tilastot_plv> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.<myOrg>.fi/rdf/ontologies/pxproNG> .

Now apache-jena-fuseki complains:
[2024-05-03 06:05:43] Fuseki     INFO  [1] 400 Parse error: [line: 1, col: 26] Premature end of file: [EOF] (13 ms)

I don't understand where the parse error comes from as the nq-file is created  as a backup by the same version of jena-fuseki.

"Error 404: No endpoint: /test/update" -- it is called /ds or /ds/udpate in you example.

"--file" is for loading a file into a memory dataset as the server starts. --update is not needed. Any command line setup of the database is "instead of" a configuration file.

apache-jena-fuseki-3.13.1 is quite old (October 2019) The current version is 5.0.0.

We are going to deploy jena-fuseki in docker container. We have to use at most jena-fuseki 4.0, because the latest version 4.8 here https://hub.docker.com/r/stain/jena-fuseki/tags does not work (https://github.com/apache/jena/issues/2267). That's the reason for using erarlier version in unit tests, too.

--data-binary ds_2024-04-25_13-58-06.nq is missing a @ to send the file contents

Great, and thanks so much with your patiency! Now it really works !

If you want to load a dataset, use /ds/data endpoint and PUT, or POST for adding data, using curl.
The Content-type header should be set.
curl -T D.ttl --header "Content-type: text/turtle" http://localhost:3030/ds

Another way, from Java, is to use the GSP (Graph) and DSP (Dataset) classes.
(not 3.13.1)

I downloaded rdf2rdf and tried to convert to ttl, but didn't manage:  ~/jena_for_unit_testing/apache-jena-fuseki-3.13.1> java -jar rdf2rdf-1.0.2-2.3.1.jar ds_2024-04-25_13-58-06.nq.gz .ttl
converting ds_2024-04-25_13-58-06.nq.gz to ds_2024-04-25_13-58-06.ttl (RDF/XML to Turtle)
[Fatal Error] unknown:namespace:1:7: Element or attribute "http:" do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName:)?NCName.
org.openrdf.rio.RDFParseException: Element or attribute "http:" do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName:)?NCName. [line 1, column 7]

Related to this I just edited my question

rdf2rdf (there are several such projects) is not related to Apache Jena. org.openrdf.rio is not Apache Jena.

The Jena format converter is called riot. Because in general n-quads can't be converted to RDF/XML, you'll have to tell riot the syntax is N-Triples using --syntax.

And where can I download riot? Please don't tell me to this page https://jena.apache.org/download/index.cgi. I didn't find it from there...

"apache-jena – contains the APIs, SPARQL engine, the TDB native RDF database and command line tools" - the table "Apache Jena Commands"

This command  ~/jena_for_unit_testing/apache-jena-3.13.1> ./bin/riot --syntax N-Triples --out=ttl ../apache-jena-fuseki-3.13.1/ds_2024-04-25_13-58-06.nq failed with ERROR    :: [line: 125, col: 160] Triple not terminated by DOT: [IRI:http://www.myorg.fi/tilasto/tilastot_slv]

line 125 is actually terminated by dot, but the coulumn is 204. Just too long lines for riot I guess, but don't know how to fix

riot has no such limit. Bad encoding and bad IRIs can cause errors.

I managed to get rid of the problem, but the resulting ttl-file was just 19 KB whereas the nq-file was grater than 100 MB. So I edited my original question again. If you could check it.

400 Parse error: [line: 1, col: 26] -- I can't reproduce that. What exactly is the data? What does running the server with "-v" say?

You can upload the whole file (ds_2024-04-25_13-58-06.nq) from here: https://github.com/jamietti/jena. For some reason I can still upload the same dataset ds_2024-04-25_13-58-06.nq via GUI.

That file parses for me. It is not valid Turtle or N-triples though - it has named graphs in it. Try --header "Content-type: application/n-quads". the UI uses the file extension to determine the syntax.

That content-type is already mentioned in my question after last Edit
